# Use the MSBuild plugin in Jenkins to run code as an admin

Tags: jenkins, msbuild

I'm trying to get Jenkins to run the MSBuild as an admin on Visual Studio. Is there a configuration param I can add to the exe call to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

So far as I know the only option is to run the Jenkins node agent with an Admin privileges account.